# Java: Actionlistener identifier expected error

Tags: java, overriding, actionlistener

I am trying to create a method to get input from a user in a textfield by using an ActionListener. However, when i compile i keep getting this error:

```
Quiz.java:36: error: <identifier> expected
  tfInput.addActionListener(new  a ActionListener() {
```

**Code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Quiz implements ActionListener {

private static Label lblInput;         
private static TextField tfInput;  
private static String cityIn;
private static TextField tfOutput;       

public void europe() {
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();      
   frame.setLayout(null);

   lblInput = new Label("Skriv in huvudstaden i : "); // Construct Label
   lblInput.setBounds(40,30,300,40);
   frame.add(lblInput);

   tfInput = new TextField(10);
   tfInput.setBounds(40,70,300,40);
   frame.add(tfInput);     

   tfOutput = new TextField(10); // allocate TextField
   tfOutput.setEditable(false);  // read-only
   tfOutput.setBounds(100,30,300,40);
   frame.add(tfOutput);

   frame.setTitle("Europa"); 
   frame.setSize(375, 150);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   frame.setVisible(true);

}

   tfInput.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
         String inLand = tfInput.getText(); 

      }       
   });   
 }
```

I cannot understand what could be causing this.

Comment: you are missing a `)` in `tfInput.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() `

Comment: Looks like this piece of code isn't part of the above method?

Comment: Where am I missing a `(`?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way maybe:

```
  frame.setVisible(true);
  tfInput.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() {

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
         String inLand = tfInput.getText(); 
       }       
    });   
  }
 }
```